# What is a class with only attributes called?

Tags: java, oop

Is there a name or nickname for a class that only contain attributes (like a c struct)? Like DialogParameters in this example:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog {

  public static class DialogParameters {
    public String dialogTitle;
    public String helpId;
  }

  public MyDialog(DialogParameters parameters) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that really valid code?, can a class be static?

Comment: Yes, it is valid in Java. It means that the class is standalone - that is, it does not need any other instance "around" it to exist. Every top level classes defined in an own java file is implicitly static. To instance this class you write new MyDialog.DialogParameters();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), or value object.

Answer (score 1):

POJO (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)